# Can I set IDEA so that ';' must be used otherwise it will not be compiled?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

or by setting Maven's check-style-plugin and something like it in gradle?

thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you want to do that? semicolon is optional in kotlin for a reason

Comment: @sidgate To unify the style. Because I mainly used java before, I used to end with a semicolon. Now when I use Kotlin, some codes will end with semicolons and some do not. This makes me very unhappy. So I hope to use IDEA to unify the style that must end with a semicolon.

Comment: how about the other way? intellij already gives a warning for unnecessary semicolon

Comment: Semicolon creates unnecessary noise in the code, however you can use third party linters such as [ktlint](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint) to configure code styles.

Comment: It is best to learn to adapt to coding conventions of the language you're using. You might want to work for a company someday that uses that language. And people will have an easier time helping you here when you have questions. The included linter for Kotlin already provides a warning by default when you use an unnecessary semicolon. I used Java/C/C# exclusively for a decade and it only took a couple days of Kotlin to stop accidentally using semicolons.